# Strange code highlighting issue in C# code

Tags: support, bug, syntax-highlighting, code

In this post:

[How to identify html tags in html string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66676044/6865932)

The language is not being recognized, the first string inside the quotes and the comments are all off.

When I try to answer, the same strange code highlighting appears:

[image]

But if I copy/paste the code to another post it seems to work fine.

> [image]

I also tried with code guards, and explicitly indicating c# as the language, but it's the same.

If I paste it here, it doesn't recognize any language:

```
var htmlstring = "<p><span><br> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>";

// find last index of <br>
var last = htmlstring.LastIndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var tempstr = htmlstring.Remove(last, 4); // remove <br>

//find first index of <br>
var first = htmlstring.IndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var finalstr = tempstr.Remove(first, 4); // remove <br>
```

#### Edit:

Things got weirder still, as @rene pointed out, using `cs` or `lang-cs` here in meta works, and `c#` or `lang-c#` does nothing, right? Well yes, here, but in the original post, now it works:

> [image]

I did try that before and it wasn't working, but now it seems to be fine.

Can anyone shed some light about the apparent selective nature of this weird bug?

Comment: It looks like a bug if you use c# or `lang-c#`. Try `lang-cs` instead.

Comment: @rene, I'll try that and get back to you, I also added the bug tag.

Comment: Use it on a code fence

Comment: It is a bug. I can't repro reliably. I've deleted my answer for now.

Comment: @rene: Don't worry about my edits. Thank you for your continuous support on Meta!

Comment: @rene, your answer did provide more clarity about the situation, so thank you.

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-c# -->` seems to work, aside from the `var` highlight. replacing `c#` with `cs` fixes that.

Comment: Also, the question is tagged `html`, so it's probably assuming the code is HTML.

Comment: undeleted my answer. I have a slightly better repro described.

Comment: @Cerbrus, yes that works, and also using c# code fence, or the others rene mentioned, but the behavior is variable deppending on where the code is used. The point about the `html` tag looks like a good point. It may be related to the OP original tag, that may also explain why here it doesn't recognize any language.

Comment: @rene, yes, it's a step in the right direction. What do you think about the possibly the OP tags being both C# and html causing it?

Comment: @Cerbrus, though I appreciate the edit and correction it does hinder a bit this meta post, I didn't correct it so the bug becomes apparent to the readers of this post, post. Anyway if not for the bug I would have deleted it, because in a conversation with the OP we agreed that the answer was unusable because of company constraints.

Comment: @anastaciu That is why I test on MSO (aka this site) so I'm not bothered / extra confused by what tags are used.

Comment: @anastaciu: you still have the screenshots here, though

Comment: @Cerbrus, not the one with the bad code recognition, anyway I added a note at the beginning so that people can look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `c#` the highlighter picks nothing. Only if I add a space after the # or switch to lang-c# the highlighter seems to be behaving sometimes as designed.  But the lang-c# gives me better results then only using c# as highlight hint.

```
var htmlstring = "<p><span><br> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>";

// find last index of <br>
var last = htmlstring.LastIndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var tempstr = htmlstring.Remove(last, 4); // remove <br>

//find first index of <br>
var first = htmlstring.IndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var finalstr = tempstr.Remove(first, 4); // remove <br>
```

When using `cs` or `lang-cs` the highlighter works.

```cs
var htmlstring = "<p><span><br> text <b>text &nbsp;<br></b>text <br></span></p>";

// find last index of <br>
var last = htmlstring.LastIndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var tempstr = htmlstring.Remove(last, 4); // remove <br>

//find first index of <br>
var first = htmlstring.IndexOf("<br>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var finalstr = tempstr.Remove(first, 4); // remove <br>
```

This is either a bug or the guidance on [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) needs to be adjusted as that states:

> - **C#** `lang-cs`, `lang-csharp`, `lang-c#`

That last entry doesn't seem to work (reliable) anymore.

Comment: Now it got even weirder, I tried all that before and it wasn´t working at all, but now it does, even with c#, I'm baffled.

Comment: sorry @honk I submitted my answer too early while I was not even close to be ready to post. Your edit was/is correct but the version I was working on was more complete so I completely overwrote your version. I'll delete next time so you won't have to spend time on my crappy answer.

Comment: Take a look https://postimg.cc/z3BYsfcz

Comment: The strangest thing to me is that if I copy the exact code to another answer it works fine, so it's a selective bug, it appears :)

Comment: Well given that the issue is easily fixable it doesn't seem very prductive to lose more time on this, thanks for your answer.

Comment: [Maintainer of Highlight.js here] I'd say this is a SE bug.  We definitely ship a `c#` alias that maps back to `csharp`.  So SE is breaking that for some reason (or purpose or on accident). https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/csharp.js#L238

Comment: @JoshGoebel yeah, I have the impression that the # from c# gets stripped leading to the lang-c highlighter being used, or none at all. But there is some weird behavior on the SE site and not a highlight.js issue. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: Something fishy is going on with the `#`, I agree. Josh mentioned that it's definitely included in highlight.js, and I can confirm [it is indeed listed as an alias in SE's highlight-loader.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pENEM.png) for c#, so it doesn't appear to be a highlighter problem per-say.